# Can't import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation

Tags: java, import

If I try to use

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
```

it says this statement can not be resolved. What could be wrong? I am using jdk1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's *exactly* your import line? It certainly works for me. Try just compiling this trivial test class:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
public class Test {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could the classpath you pass to your compiler be wrong?

If you are pointing to the wrong version of the java libraries, or somehow not including them at all, the compiler will not be able to resolve the class import.